# Why does rand() function returns 1804289383 on online compilers?

Tags: c++

I'm keeping on trying on various online editor,but the result is the same

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  
int main() {
    std::cout << rand(); 
}
```

Comment: Because you haven't called `srand()`, which is a requirement for obtaining random numbers from `rand()`

Comment: _"...srand() seeds the pseudo-random number generator used by rand(). If rand() is used before any calls to srand(), rand() behaves __as if it was seeded with srand(1)__..."_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand

Comment: Side note: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) A good and humorous look at how easy it is to get things wrong with `rand`, how hard it is to get them right, and the modern C++ solution that you should be using instead.